# Prove this limit is finite and give its value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I have the differential equation $$y'(t)=\alpha y(t)-\beta y^2(t),y(0)=N_0$$
and have solved it to get the solution $$y(t)=\frac1{(\frac1{N_0}-\frac \beta \alpha)e^{-\alpha t}+\frac \beta \alpha}$$ My question asks me to rewrite this with $M=\frac \alpha \beta$ where $N_0<M$, giving me $$y(t)=\frac M{(\frac {M-N_0}{N_0})e^{-\alpha t}+1}$$ I now have to prove that $\lim_{t \mapsto \infty}y(t)$ is finite, and give its value. I have literally no idea how to approach this, can anyone help?

Comment: The only place where $t$ appears is in the exponent $e^{-\alpha t}$; what's the limit of _that_ as $t\to\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your solution is correct:
$$
y(t)=\frac M{(\frac {M-N_0}{N_0})e^{-\alpha t}+1}
$$
then we can note that the only term dependent on t is $\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha t}$ which when $t\rightarrow\infty$ tends to 0. So essential your equation becomes
$$
y(t)\rightarrow\frac{M}{\left(\frac {M-N_0}{N_0}\right)\cdot 0 + 1} = M
$$
Does this help?